# Format values on entire column SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date-format

I have a column which has values of format "01-01-2012" and I need to change it to "01.01.2012". I have to do the same for all the entries of that coloumn.

Could you please suggest a way to do it? I need a general SQL statement.

Thanks

Comment: What data type is this column?  I'm assuming some form of `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`?

Comment: @Jon Thats right. It is VARCHAR.

Comment: Store dates using the appropriate DATE data type. Display them using settings appropriate to the client's locale, e.g. with a bit of javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html):

```
update tablename set column_name=REPLACE(column_name,'-','.')
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use a basic `UPDATE` statement.  In this case, you would update your entire table and for each row, set the value of the column to the formatted value.  The basic outline would be like so:

```
UPDATE [TableName]
SET    [ColumnName] = [FormattingExpression]
```

An example of [FormattingExpression] could be:

```
REPLACE ([ColumnName], '-' , '.' )
```

This would [replace](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) all instances of '-' with '.' for the values in the `[ColumnName]` column of your `[TableName]` table.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS (
  SELECT '12-12-2012' AS mydate FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT '07-23-2013' FROM DUAL
)SELECT REPLACE(mydate, '-', '.') mynewdate
 FROM TEST_DATA
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replaced the - with .

```
REPLACE ( '01-01-2012' , '-' , '.' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `str_to_date`

```
UPDATE `table` SET `date_col` = str_to_date(`date_col`,'%d.%m.%Y')
```

[**STR_TO_DATE(str,format)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the datatype is specified in the comments to the question.

Comment: I really appreciate all your answers. That works great. I cannot mark all as correct. But Bhushan was the first one to answer and others you have my upvote. Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
update table_name set column_name = replace (column_name , '-' , '.' );
```